# How to pre-populate the selection in Multilist field from a query in sitecore sxa

Tags: sxa

Is there a way to use sitecore query on multilist field where it can pre populate the items on right hand side ? 
I need to pre populate items from a particular template in descending order based on a field and limit as 10. By default the selection will be pre populated and later user can select anyother item and rearrange it.

Comment: Are the pre-populated items always the same? If so, you can specify them in the standard values. If not, you will likely need to implement an `item:created` event handler to dynamically add the items you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you have complex logic to fill the Multilist with items you can use code data source like we are doing it in e.g. Rendering Variants:

```
public class MyCodeDatasource : IDataSource
{          
    public Item[] ListQuery(Item item)
    {
        string url = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContext>().RawUrl;
        if (url.Contains("hdl"))
        {
            //if you need context item you can access session object using hdl and get the item ID from there                                
        }

        //put your logic to get items here and rearrange them as you want

        return Array.Empty<Item>();
    }
}
```

You can use this like this:

[image]