# Sxa tokens not taken into account in code query

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api, sitecore-query, custom-field

I am working on a custom field which is based on :https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/A/Advance_Image_Field.aspx

I am trying to make it suitable for SXA by changing the way to find thumbnails. So instead of looking for an ID I would like to use query with SXA tokens.

Sadly it throws an error :

> Field control has failed to render: End of string expected at position
>   5.Details Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: End of string expected at position 5. at Sitecore.Data.Query.QueryParser.Raise(String error)
>   at Sitecore.Data.Query.QueryParser.DoParse(String query) at
>   Sitecore.Data.Query.Query..ctor(String query) at
>   Sitecore.Data.Query.Query.SelectSingleItem(String query, QueryContext
>   contextNode, Database database) at
>   Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase.SelectSingleItem(String query) at
>   HagerDeep.Foundation.Media.Fields.ImageWithFocusCrop.GetThumbnails()
>   in
>   D:\BitBucket\DEEP2\src\Foundation\Media\code\Fields\ImageWithFocusCrop.cs:line
>   639 at
>   HagerDeep.Foundation.Media.Fields.ImageWithFocusCrop.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) in
>   D:\BitBucket\DEEP2\src\Foundation\Media\code\Fields\ImageWithFocusCrop.cs:line
>   202 at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.EditorFieldContainer.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)

Here's my code that throw the error:

```
var thumbnailFolderItem = Client.ContentDatabase.SelectSingleItem(ThumbnailsFolderQuery);
```

With the following query using SXA token :

```
query:$site/*[@@name='Presentation']/*[@@name='Thumbnails Ratio']/*[@@name='Fallback Thumbnail Folder']
```

Do I use the right function ? Or does the SXA tokens are not supported in code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject `ITokenResolver` and call `Resolve()` method.

```
ITokenResolver tokenResolver = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITokenResolver>()
string query = tokenResolver.Resolve(MY_QUERY, CONTEXT_ITEM);
```

and then for example:

```
CONTEXT_ITEM.Axes.SelectItems(query)
```

You can, of course, use construction injection instead of using ServiceLocator for getting `ITokenResolver`.

Comment: Hi Dawid, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I can't get the context item since I'm in a Field class which inherit from LinkBase. So the context item is the field itself in the core database. Moreover the method GetService<ITokenResolver>() ask for a type and I don't know which one to give it.

Comment: Add the following usage: `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`. There is almost always a way to get the context item. It is just not obvious in some cases. Check my answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17263/how-to-pre-populate-the-selection-in-multilist-field-from-a-query-in-sitecore-sx. If URL contains "hdl" query string than it means that you can get object form session using this "hdl" and inside it you will find context item id.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I am not a dependency injection expert but I finally found how to do it thanks to you. I'll add an answer to explain what I actually did.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

1. I am using 3.7.1 version of the
   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.TokenResolution.dll so there is no service
   for token resolution but a static class.
2. Then for getting current
       item it was really easy actually... Just add a property in my custom field.

> Use those if Sitecore.XA.Foundation.TokenResolution is 3.8.0 or above

- using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;
- using
  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

> In my case only that one was useful since it's not a service in 3.7.1

- using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.TokenResolution;

  ```
  public class ImageWithFocusCrop : LinkBase
  {
      //Will get the target item ID
      public string ItemID { get; set; }

      private string GetThumbnails()
      {
           var targetItemID = ItemID;
           var targetItem = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(targetItemID));
           //For 3.8.0 version and above
           ITokenResolver tokenResolver = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITokenResolver>();
           string query = tokenResolver.Resolve(ThumbnailsFolderQuery, targetItem );
           //For 3.7.1 version
           string query = TokenResolver.Resolve(ThumbnailsFolderQuery, targetItem);

           var thumbnailFolderItem = targetItem.Axes.SelectItems(query);
      }
  }
  ```